# Android: Start Activity after 5 or more clicks

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener

I have a `onClick` listener which starts an activity using intent, but how to make the listener to fire the Activity intent only when the user click five times or more?

```
public boolean onClick(View v) {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, loginActivity.class);
    activity.startActivity(myIntent);

    return false;   
}
```

Here I am going to login Activity. How can I get back to previous activity after login successful?

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    String username = Username.getText().toString();
    String password = Password.getText().toString();

    if(username.equals("guest") && password.equals("guest")) {
        lResult.setText("Login successful.");
    } else {
        lResult.setText("Login failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a static variable in program which will increment on each click.

When you click count reach 5 then trigger code to start LoginActivity.

```
static int i = 0;

@override
public void onClick(View view) {
    i++;
    if (i == 5) {
        i = 0;
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, loginActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: .hi..can i put delay in onlclick..problem is...when i click 3 times and pause for couple of sec and again i hit 2 time the intent is firing...i want it only when i click continuosly 5 times...

Comment: What ! ? inOnclick "i == 5" ? not have logic, and a foolishness

Answer (score 1):

You can try to build  a counter which count the clicks and from the 5th clicks let him go forward

To turn back to the previous activity just call

```
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a static counter to your activity.

```
static int clickCount;
```

In your onClick:

```
if(clickCount++<5){return;}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the fist question just a a counter variable on the class and increment in on onClick() and check it its >= 5 before         starting the intent.

```
    int clickCounter;

    public boolean onClick(View v) {

            clickCounter++;

            if (clickCounter >= 5) {

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity, loginActivity.class);
                    activity.startActivity(myIntent);
            }

            return false;   
    }
```

For the second question you must take into account whether previous Activity must keep exactly the same aspect or update with user data. Take a look at Activity.startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode) for calling an activity and get a result value from it.
 -

Comment: ..Thank you..the second activity doesn't need to get any data..simply it should get back to previous activity..